I have a vue.js & three.js code and how to hidden coordinate part in three.js?
Everyone, I have a vue & three.js code. and i wanna hidden the part which shows in the picture.
I have no experience in three.js and i don't know how to fix it.
i used scene, camera, renderer, control, material
I tried to hidden coordinate but failed, how to hidden it?
Look forward to hearing from you soon.
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
import * as THREE from 'three'
import { STLLoader } from 'three/addons/loaders/STLLoader.js'
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/addons/loaders/GLTFLoader.js'
import { TransformControls } from 
'three/addons/controls/TransformControls.js'
import { EffectComposer } from 
'three/addons/postprocessing/EffectComposer.js'
import { RenderPass } from 
'three/addons/postprocessing/RenderPass.js'
import { ShaderPass } from 
'three/addons/postprocessing/ShaderPass.js'
import { OutlinePass } from 
'three/addons/postprocessing/OutlinePass.js'
import { OutputPass } from 
'three/addons/postprocessing/OutputPass.js'
import { FXAAShader } from 'three/addons/shaders/FXAAShader.js'
import { get } from '@/utils/request'

 let camera, scene, renderer, control
 let transforming = false
 let composer, effectFXAA, outlinePass

let isUserInteracting = false,
onPointerDownMouseX = 0,
onPointerDownMouseY = 0,
lon = 0,
onPointerDownLon = 0,
lat = 0,
onPointerDownLat = 0,
phi = 0,
theta = 0

const gl_renderer = ref()
const assets = ref([])

let selectedObjects = []

const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster()
const mouse = new THREE.Vector2()

const obj3d = new THREE.Object3D()
const group = new THREE.Group()

const params = {
edgeStrength: 3.0,
edgeGlow: 0.0,
edgeThickness: 1.0,
pulsePeriod: 0,
rotate: false,
usePatternTexture: false,

}
init()

function init() {
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true })
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio)
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
renderer.setAnimationLoop(animate)

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    75,
    window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
    1,
    1100
)
control = new TransformControls(camera, renderer.domElement)
control.addEventListener('change', render)

control.addEventListener('mounsedown', () => {
    transforming = true
})
control.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
    transforming = false
})

scene = new THREE.Scene()
// scene.add( new THREE.GridHelper( 5, 10, 0x888888, 0x444444 ) );

const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(50, 15, 20)
// invert the geometry on the x-axis so that all of the faces point 
inward
geometry.scale(-1, 1, 1)

const texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('/pano.png')
texture.colorSpace = THREE.SRGBColorSpace
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture })
// const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffff00 } 
);
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
scene.add(mesh) //panorama
scene.add(control) //Transformation Control

//Building Virtual Walls Start
var vertices = [
    [-2.7633402, 1.6047263, -1.6],
    [-1.7463672, 1.6007595, -1.6],
    [-1.7485583, 0.49777806, -1.6],
    [-7.764425, 0.5168958, -1.6],
    [-7.7677183, -0.6989663, -1.6],
    [-1.9021894, -0.7084358, -1.6],
    [-1.9107, -2.9390538, -1.6],
    [2.1903515, -2.9501178, -1.6],
    [2.1916685, -1.3303574, -1.6],
    [2.3187919, -1.3308245, -1.6],
    [2.3199596, -0.64071184, -1.6],
    [2.3847497, -0.64091146, -1.6],
    [2.4111028, 5.4470587, -1.6],
    [0.40475827, 5.448264, -1.6],
    [0.40593255, 5.824964, -1.6],
    [-2.765071, 5.8383408, -1.6],
    [-2.7633402, 1.6047263, 1.4818056],
    [-1.7463672, 1.6007595, 1.4818056],
    [-1.7485583, 0.49777806, 1.4818056],
    [-7.764425, 0.5168958, 1.4818056],
    [-7.7677183, -0.6989663, 1.4818056],
    [-1.9021894, -0.7084358, 1.4818056],
    [-1.9107, -2.9390538, 1.4818056],
    [2.1903515, -2.9501178, 1.4818056],
    [2.1916685, -1.3303574, 1.4818056],
    [2.3187919, -1.3308245, 1.4818056],
    [2.3199596, -0.64071184, 1.4818056],
    [2.3847497, -0.64091146, 1.4818056],
    [2.4111028, 5.4470587, 1.4818056],
    [0.40475827, 5.448264, 1.4818056],
    [0.40593255, 5.824964, 1.4818056],
    [-2.765071, 5.8383408, 1.4818056],
]
var v = vertices.map((el) => new THREE.Vector3(el[1], el[2], - 
el[0]))

var lines = [
    [0, 1],
    [1, 2],
    [2, 3],
    [3, 4],
    [4, 5],
    [5, 6],
    [6, 7],
    [7, 8],
    [8, 9],
    [9, 10],
    [10, 11],
    [11, 12],
    [12, 13],
    [13, 14],
    [14, 15],
    [15, 0],
    [16, 17],
    [17, 18],
    [18, 19],
    [19, 20],
    [20, 21],
    [21, 22],
    [22, 23],
    [23, 24],
    [24, 25],
    [25, 26],
    [26, 27],
    [27, 28],
    [28, 29],
    [29, 30],
    [30, 31],
    [31, 16],
    [0, 16],
    [1, 17],
    [2, 18],
    [3, 19],
    [4, 20],
    [5, 21],
    [6, 22],
    [7, 23],
    [8, 24],
    [9, 25],
    [10, 26],
    [11, 27],
    [12, 28],
    [13, 29],
    [14, 30],
    [15, 31],
]
const planes = [
    [0, 16],
    [1, 17],
    [2, 18],
    [3, 19],
    [4, 20],
    [5, 21],
    [6, 22],
    [7, 23],
    [8, 24],
    [9, 25],
    [10, 26],
    [11, 27],
    [12, 28],
    [13, 29],
    [14, 30],
    [15, 31],
]
var low_planes = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(planes))
var high_planes = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(planes))

low_planes.forEach((el) => el.push((el[0] + 1) % 16))
high_planes.forEach((el) => el.push(16 + ((el[1] - 1) % 16)))
var plane_points = [...high_planes, ...low_planes].flat().map((el) 
=> v[el])
lines.forEach((el) => {
    const linemat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0x0000ff })
    const linegeom = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints([
        v[el[0]],
        v[el[1]],
    ])
    const line = new THREE.Line(linegeom, linemat)

    // scene.add(line);
})

const maskShaderMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: {
        color: { value: new THREE.Color(0x000000) },
        opacity: { value: 0.5 },
    },
    vertexShader: `
    varying vec3 vNormal;
    void main() {
        vNormal = normalize(normalMatrix * normal);
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * 
vec4(position, 1.0);
    }
`,
    fragmentShader: `
    uniform vec3 color;
    uniform float opacity;
    varying vec3 vNormal;
    void main() {
        float intensity = dot(vNormal, vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0));
        gl_FragColor = vec4(color * intensity, opacity);
    }
`,
    transparent: true,
})

var wallgeom = new 
THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(plane_points)
wallgeom.computeVertexNormals()

var wallmat = maskShaderMaterial

var object = new THREE.Mesh(wallgeom, wallmat)
object.renderOrder = 1
scene.add(object)

//BUilding virtual walls end

//--------------------Light-------------------------------//
scene.add(new THREE.HemisphereLight(0x8d7c7c, 0x494966, 3))

addShadowedLight(1, 1, 1, 0xffffff, 3.5)
addShadowedLight(0.5, 1, -1, 0xffd500, 3)

const loader = new GLTFLoader().setPath(
    'https://playcanvas- 
public.s3.amazonaws.com/data/objects/raw_blenderkit_assets/be5ee38a- 
b1ce-4542-ad08-6e3505e479f0/'
)
loader.load('processed_asset.glb', async function (gltf) {
    const model = gltf.scene

    // wait until the model can be added to the scene without 
blocking due to shader compilation

    await renderer.compileAsync(model, camera, scene)
    console.log(model)
    control.attach(model.children[0])
    model.children[0].position.set(0.2, -1.6, 5)
    model.children[0].castShadow = true
    model.children[0].receiveShadow = true
    selectedObjects.push(model.children[0])
    scene.add(model.children[0])

    render()
})

composer = new EffectComposer(renderer)
const renderPass = new RenderPass(scene, camera)
composer.addPass(renderPass)

outlinePass = new OutlinePass(
    new THREE.Vector2(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight),
    scene,
    camera
)
outlinePass.visibleEdgeColor.set('#0000ff')
outlinePass.hiddenEdgeColor.set('#ff0000')
outlinePass.edgeStrength = Number(3)
outlinePass.edgeThickness = Number(1)
outlinePass.usePatternTexture = false

composer.addPass(outlinePass)
const outputPass = new OutputPass()
composer.addPass(outputPass)

effectFXAA = new ShaderPass(FXAAShader)
effectFXAA.uniforms['resolution'].value.set(
    1 / window.innerWidth,
    1 / window.innerHeight
)
composer.addPass(effectFXAA)

document.addEventListener('wheel', onDocumentMouseWheel)

//

document.addEventListener('dragover', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy'
})

document.addEventListener('dragenter', function () {
    document.body.style.opacity = 0.5
})

document.addEventListener('dragleave', function () {
    document.body.style.opacity = 1
})

document.addEventListener('drop', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault()

    const reader = new FileReader()
    reader.addEventListener('load', function (event) {
        material.map.image.src = event.target.result
        material.map.needsUpdate = true
    })
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.dataTransfer.files[0])

    document.body.style.opacity = 1
})

//

window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize)
window.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
    switch (event.key) {
        case 'q':
            control.setSpace(control.space === 'local' ? 'world' : 
'local')
            break

        case 'Shift':
            control.setTranslationSnap(1)
            control.setRotationSnap(THREE.MathUtils.degToRad(15))
            control.setScaleSnap(0.25)
            break

        case 'w':
            control.setMode('translate')
            break

        case 'e':
            control.setMode('rotate')
            break

        case 'r':
            control.setMode('scale')
            break
    }
})
document.addEventListener('pointermove', onPointerMove)
document.addEventListener('pointerup', onPointerUp)
}

function onWindowResize() {
const width = gl_renderer.value.getBoundingClientRect().width
const height = gl_renderer.value.getBoundingClientRect().height
camera.aspect = width / height
camera.updateProjectionMatrix()

renderer.setSize(width, height)
}

function onPointerDown(event) {
if (control.dragging) return

if (event.isPrimary === false) return

isUserInteracting = true

onPointerDownMouseX = event.clientX
onPointerDownMouseY = event.clientY

onPointerDownLon = lon
onPointerDownLat = lat
}

function onPointerMove(event) {
const width = gl_renderer.value.getBoundingClientRect().width
const height = gl_renderer.value.getBoundingClientRect().height
if (control.dragging) return
if (event.isPrimary === false) return
if (isUserInteracting) {
    lon = (onPointerDownMouseX - event.clientX) * 0.1 + 
onPointerDownLon
    lat = (event.clientY - onPointerDownMouseY) * 0.1 + 
onPointerDownLat
}
mouse.x = (event.clientX / width) * 2 - 1
mouse.y = -(event.clientY / height) * 2 + 1

checkIntersection()
}

function addSelectedObject(object) {
selectedObjects = []
selectedObjects.push(object)
}

function checkIntersection() {
raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera)

const intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(scene, true)

if (intersects.length > 0) {
    const selectedObject = intersects[intersects.length - 1].object
    //   addSelectedObject(selectedObject);
    outlinePass.selectedObjects = selectedObjects
} else {
    // outlinePass.selectedObjects = [];
}
}
function onPointerUp() {
if (event.isPrimary === false) return

isUserInteracting = false
}

function onDocumentMouseWheel(event) {
const fov = camera.fov + event.deltaY * 0.05

camera.fov = THREE.MathUtils.clamp(fov, 10, 75)

camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
}

function addShadowedLight(x, y, z, color, intensity) {
const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(color, 
intensity)
directionalLight.position.set(x, y, z)
scene.add(directionalLight)

directionalLight.castShadow = true

const d = 1
directionalLight.shadow.camera.left = -d
directionalLight.shadow.camera.right = d
directionalLight.shadow.camera.top = d
directionalLight.shadow.camera.bottom = -d

directionalLight.shadow.camera.near = 1
directionalLight.shadow.camera.far = 4

directionalLight.shadow.bias = -0.002
}

function animate() {
if (control.dragging) return

lat = Math.max(-85, Math.min(85, lat))
phi = THREE.MathUtils.degToRad(90 - lat)
theta = THREE.MathUtils.degToRad(lon)

const x = 500 * Math.sin(phi) * Math.cos(theta)
const y = 500 * Math.cos(phi)
const z = 500 * Math.sin(phi) * Math.sin(theta)

camera.lookAt(x, y, z)
composer.render()
// renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function render() {
composer.render()
renderer.render(scene, camera)
}

onMounted(() => {
gl_renderer.value.appendChild(renderer.domElement)
gl_renderer.value.style.touchAction = 'none'
gl_renderer.value.addEventListener('pointerdown', onPointerDown)
get({ url: '/furniture/assets' }).then((respData) => {
    console.log(respData)
    assets.value = respData.data
})
animate()
})
</script>

<template>
<div id="container" ref="gl_renderer" style="position: relative"> 
</div>
</template>

<style></style>

